# The navigation not work in a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-fbsdk

I have a function to login with facebook using react-native-fbsdk:

```
handleFacebookLogin () {
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Login isCancelled');
    } else {
      alert('Login ok')
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ListaUf')
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error);
  }
);
}
```

When the user is successfully logged in, I want to navigate to the next page, which is called `ListaUf`.

if I use the `this.props.navigation.navigate('ListaUf')` in a button or in a `componentDidMount`, this works correctly.

On the emulator, appears a yellow message:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

The `alert('Login ok')` works, but `this.props.navigation.navigate('ListaUf')` does not work.

Comment: Are you using`import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';` anywhere? If you do `console.log(this.props)` in the `else` statement, what do you get? The `navigation` object should be visible in the Chrome Console (Hitting F12 in the browser).

Comment: @ThomasDarvik, if I use the `this.props.navigation.navigate('ListaUf')` in a button or in a componentDidMount, this works correctly.

Comment: @ThomasDarvik I reveive: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.navega()')

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to call the variable `this.navega()` somewhere. Check your code. The TypeError might also reference a point in the code, where the problem occurred.

Comment: sorry, the correct is: `this.props.navigation`

Comment: Do you import the navigation lib somewhere? Like I said in my first comment, for example with an import statement on the top of your class like `import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170470/discussion-between-thomas-darvik-and-italo-rodrigo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing context of `this`. You need to either [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your functions or use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). If `handleFacebookLogin` is being triggered with a button press or similar you need to `bind` it too.

**With bind**

```
handleFacebookLogin () {
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('Login isCancelled');
      } else {
        alert('Login ok')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ListaUf')
      }
    }.bind(this),
    function(error) {
      alert('Error: ' + error);
    }
  );
}
```

**With lambda**

```
handleFacebookLogin = () => {
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
    (result) => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('Login isCancelled');
      } else {
        alert('Login ok')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ListaUf')
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert('Error: ' + error);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I try the two examples you write and receive a yellow message: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you need to bind handleFacebookLogin function too

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add curly braces around the navigation

export default ({navigation}) =>